# Python project. Error: "QWindowsPipeWriter::write failed. (The handle is invalid.)"

Tags: python, pip, pyqt, pyqtgraph, pyqtdeploy

I am newbie to programming :). Created a python project with GUI support. Converted it to an .exe file through pyinstaller. The problem is that when pressing the GUI buttons in the console, the error "QWindowsPipeWriter::write failed. (The handle is invalid.)" is issued. There is no such problem with the .py file, it only happens with the .exe file.

Ось мій код:

```
from cProfile import label
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QInputDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("FACEID")
        
        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)  # Set the size of the window
        self.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(bg2.jpg);")

        self.process = QProcess()
        self.process.started.connect(self.on_process_started)

        self.run_script()  

        self.command1Button = QPushButton("Додати нове обличчя")
        self.command1Button.clicked.connect(self.send_command1)
        self.command1Button.setFixedSize(380, 30)
        self.command1Button.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: black;  font-weight: bold; font-family: Georgia, serif")

        self.command2Button = QPushButton("Запустити FACE ID")
        self.command2Button.clicked.connect(self.send_command2)
        self.command2Button.setFixedSize(380, 40)
        self.command2Button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #7fff00; color: black; font-weight: bold; font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 20px")

        self.command3Button = QPushButton("Вихід")
        self.command3Button.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.command3Button.setFixedSize(380, 30)
        self.command3Button.setStyleSheet("background-color: red; color: black; font-weight: bold; font-family: Georgia, serif")

        self.readyButton = QPushButton("Почати реєстрацію обличчя")
        self.readyButton.clicked.connect(self.send_enter)
        self.readyButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.readyButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: black; font-weight: bold; font-family: Georgia, serif")

        self.output = QTextEdit()
        self.output.setReadOnly(True)  
        
        self.imageLabel = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('photo.png')
        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.imageLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.imageLabel)  
        layout.addWidget(self.command2Button)
        layout.addWidget(self.command1Button)
        layout.addWidget(self.readyButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.command3Button)

        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(container)

    def run_script(self):
        #self.process.setWorkingDirectory("C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Робочий стіл/PK/PK")  
        self.process.start("python", ["facerecog.py"])
        started = self.process.waitForStarted(5000)
        if not started:
            print("Process did not start in time")

    def on_process_started(self):
        print("Process started")

    def send_command1(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'FACEID', 'Після введеня назви нажміть на кнопку "Почати реєстрацію обличчя":\n\nВведіть назву обличчя:')
        if ok:
            command = f"1\n{text}\n"
        self.process.write(command.encode())
        self.readyButton.setEnabled(True)

    def send_command2(self):
        command = "2\n"
        self.process.write(command.encode())

    def send_enter(self):
        command = "1\n"
        self.process.write(command.encode())

    def on_readyReadStandardOutput(self):
        data = self.process.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode()
        self.output.append(data)

    def on_readyReadStandardError(self):
        data = self.process.readAllStandardError().data().decode()
        self.output.append(data)

app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

via "self.process.state() == QProcess.Running" checked if the process is running

Comment: It is working for me, so I suggest upgrading or reinstalling pyinstaller.

Comment: @RikMulder It doesn't work equally. Can I send you the entire project so you can check it out?

Comment: I don't think that would matter. I've run the entirety of the program on my machine, and it is working. It is not working for you. I don't know what causes the error, but the only possible explanation I see is that something is going wrong with pyinstaller. This means that either, pyinstaller is doing something wrong, or some other library is not working correctly. I recommend updating your python version, the other packages, and if that is still not working, I unfortunately have no idea what else you could do.